# Not getting the correct encoding to extract body from HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, api, post, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to extract data from a government site which is rendered on display of a pop up. I checked the network console and got the POST request URL and able to replicate the request-response on Postman. Now I am trying to make the call programmatically. I tried using the default code generated by Postman but it did not work.

I am writing the code in C# and I am able to get the response but I am not able to get the correct encoding to extract the response.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://saubhagya.gov.in/dashboard/data/dashboard_saubhagya");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01";
        request.Host = "saubhagya.gov.in";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36";
        request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9");
        request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control: no-cache");
        request.Headers.Add("Pragma: no-cache");
        request.Headers.Add("Origin: http://saubhagya.gov.in");
        request.Referer = "http://saubhagya.gov.in/";
        String CookieStr = "_ga=GA1.3.590075225.1533991967; _gid=GA1.3.790472263.1533991967; saubhagyasession=BHxX%2FFfttUfxM7JhoIruGVzdq0m%2F4sGeTn95c%2BUB%2BGvJok9PkS3g9pR8vLVfeEJ1XB8UULGNThvbAeN5HfAu%2FE6qt%2F5X3qL8Yla4my0qmxSmz6Q9ztpLztCD0PyY17uWDnJgkSjSt%2BSF0B5Xh32SUsxBXHH%2BeFGwtIXdAnzSLcxC0MO8KZSiE2io4ksZO6AZ31YSxnGei6CluQzg4fCFgXvVwR4%2F00%2FKAbf0MnhLwaTtXxD0jngmDv3Rjy8enD87c20vwObHGTgcLC3KQoh2lw5L1WRF1lVLlpjzLrUoeJV3cD8o0c15bT5SA%2FV1Y8OqFPhqhpr0%2BzzG%2FbAVs6OKMmLiokl7hHrPx5NECDsmY3KzmCkNHka%2B1ueEWTv%2FTOUqH2hll2A8485gFhqFgnrh%2FKkhOb6I8lChI2QQoyHr%2B9U%3D92add88ce105d8b3ec1dd72efa1dd7ec9b9f1e52";
        CookieContainer cookiecontainer = new CookieContainer();
        string[] cookies = CookieStr.Split(';');
        foreach (string cookie in cookies)
            cookiecontainer.SetCookies(new Uri("http://saubhagya.gov.in/dashboard/data/dashboard_saubhagya"), cookie);
        request.CookieContainer = cookiecontainer;
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "ci_csrf_token=&state=35&district=638&village=645115&vtype=&discom=&search_text=&uuid=&maptype=states&kyroargs=&drilldownkey=&kyroclickid=&kyrorefreshid=&page=dashboard_saubhagya";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }



        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet)))
        {
            var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

I get an encoded/junk string as output.

Requesting for help!

Comment: Best way of debugging these issue is using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare the Postman results with your code results.  Usually the solution is to add missing html headers to your code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - however, the lack of decompression of the response was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the header you state that you accept gzip, but the response is not decompressed on your end, so just add:

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
```

Then you can remove this line because headers will be added automatically:

```
//request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
```